# Неправильно открывается ссылка

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!
Есть строка:

```
<TD  align="CENTER" ><a href="http://test.ru/'.$result_query["type_tovara"].'/'.$result_query["products_id"].'-'.$result_query["title"].'">...</a> </TD>
```

В итоге открывается следующая ссылка (к примеру):

http://test.ru/tshirts/3-Test/

Название **Test** берётся с базы данных, мне необходимо сделать так чтобы **Test** писалось не с заглавной буквы, как можно реализовать? Писать в бд с маленькой буквы - не вариант.

Вся страница php:

```html
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['auth_admin'] == "yes_auth")
{
 define('myeshop', true);
       
       if (isset($_GET["logout"]))
    {
        unset($_SESSION['auth_admin']);
        header("Location: login.php");
    }

  $_SESSION['urlpage'] = "<a href='index.php' >Главная</a> \ <a href='view_order.php' >Просмотр заказов</a>";
  
  include("include/db_connect.php");
  include("include/functions.php"); 
 
  $id = clear_string($_GET["id"]);
  $action = $_GET["action"];
  
  if (isset($action))
{
   switch ($action) {

     case 'accept':
       if ($_SESSION['accept_orders'] == '1')
       {
                     $update = mysql_query("UPDATE orders SET order_confirmed='yes' WHERE order_id = '$id'",$link);  
       }else
        {
            $msgerror = 'У вас нет прав на подтверждение заказов!';
        }

     break;
        
        case 'delete':
        
        if ($_SESSION['delete_orders'] == '1')
        {
           $delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM orders WHERE order_id = '$id'",$link); 
           header("Location: orders.php");   
        }else
        {
            $msgerror = 'У вас нет прав на удаление заказов!';
        }
        


     break;
        
 } 
    
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="jquery_confirm/jquery_confirm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_confirm/jquery_confirm.js"></script> 
    
 <title>Панель Управления - Просмотр заказов</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="block-body">
<?php
 include("include/block-header.php");
?>
<div id="block-content">
<div id="block-parameters">
<p id="title-page" >Просмотр заказа</p>
</div>
<?php
if (isset($msgerror)) echo '<p id="form-error" align="center">'.$msgerror.'</p>';


if ($_SESSION['view_orders'] == '1')
{

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id = '$id'",$link);
 
 If (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
do
{
if ($row["order_confirmed"] == 'yes')
{
    $status = '<span class="green">Обработан</span>';
} else
{
    $status = '<span class="red">Не обработан</span>';    
}


 echo '
  <p class="view-order-link" ><a class="green" href="view_order.php?id='.$row["order_id"].'&action=accept" >Подтвердить заказ</a> | <a class="delete" rel="view_order.php?id='.$row["order_id"].'&action=delete" >Удалить заказ</a></p>
  <p class="order-datetime" >'.$row["order_datetime"].'</p>
  <p class="order-number" >Заказ № '.$row["order_id"].' - '.$status.'</p>

<TABLE align="center" CELLPADDING="10" WIDTH="100%">
<TR>
<TH>№</TH>
<TH>Наименование товара</TH>
<TH>ID товара</TH>
<TH>Фото</TH>
<TH>Цена</TH>
<TH>Количество</TH>
<TH>Размер</TH>
</TR>
';
$query_product = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM buy_products,table_products WHERE buy_products.buy_id_order = '$id' AND table_products.products_id = buy_products.buy_id_product",$link);
 
$result_query = mysql_fetch_array($query_product);
do
{
$price = $price + ($result_query["price"] * $result_query["buy_count_product"]);    
$index_count =  $index_count + 1; 
echo '
 <TR>
<TD  align="CENTER" >'.$index_count.'</TD>
<TD  align="CENTER" ><a href="http://test.ru/'.$result_query["type_tovara"].'/'.$result_query["products_id"].'-'.$result_query["title"].'">'.$result_query["title"].'</a> </TD>
<TD  align="CENTER" >'.$result_query["products_id"].'</TD>
<TD  align="CENTER" ><img src="http://test.ru/uploads_images/'.$result_query["image"].'" width="50" height="50"></TD>
<TD  align="CENTER" >'.$result_query["price"].' грн</TD>
<TD  align="CENTER" >'.$result_query["buy_count_product"].'</TD>
<TD  align="CENTER" >'.$result_query["buy_cart_size"].'</TD>
</TR>

';
} while ($result_query = mysql_fetch_array($query_product));


if ($row["order_pay"] == "accepted")
{
    $statpay = '<span class="green">Оплачено</span>';
}else
{
    $statpay = '<span class="red">Не оплачено</span>';
}

echo '

</TABLE>
<ul id="info-order">
<li>Общая цена - <span>'.$price.'</span> грн</li>
<li>Способ доставки - <span>'.$row["order_delivery_method"].'</span></li>
<li>Статус заказа - '.$statpay.'</li>
<li>Дата заказа- <span>'.$row["order_datetime"].'</span></li>
</ul>


<TABLE align="center" CELLPADDING="10" WIDTH="100%">
<TR>
<TH>ФИО</TH>
<TH>Город</TH>
<TH>Отделение</TH>
<TH>Моб. номер</TH>
</TR>

 <TR>
<TD  align="CENTER" >'.$row["order_fio"].'</TD>
<TD  align="CENTER" >'.$row["order_city"].'</TD>
<TD  align="CENTER" >'.$row["order_number_np"].'</TD>
<TD  align="CENTER" >'.$row["order_phone"].'</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
 ';   
    
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
}
    
}else
{
    echo '<p id="form-error" align="center">У вас нет прав на просмотр данного раздела!</p>';  
} 
?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}else
{
    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: strtolower($result_query["title"])

Comment: @DanielProtopopov 'strtolower($result_query["title"])' - перестала вовсе открываться страница

Comment: [Функция lcfirst()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.lcfirst.php)

Comment: @RTK 'lcfirst($result_query["title"])' - так же перестаёт открываться страница

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для мультибайтных кодировок (например, если название у вас в итоге идет на русском) используйте:

```
mb_strtolower($result_query["title"], 'UTF-8');
```

UPDATE 1

Для начала попробуйте после этой строки добавить то, что указал выше:

```
$result_query = mysql_fetch_array($query_product);
$result_query["title"] = mb_strtolower($result_query["title"], 'UTF-8');
```

Еще смущает кодировка, в которой у вас выводится сама страница:

```
charset=iso-8859-1
```

Попробуйте указать более распространенную, windows-1251 или еще лучше utf-8.

UPDATE 2

Поменяйте вот этот участок:

```
$result_query = mysql_fetch_array($query_product);
do
{
$price = $price + ($result_query["price"] * $result_query["buy_count_product"]);
```

на этот:

```
$result_query = mysql_fetch_array($query_product);
$result_query["title"] = mb_strtolower($result_query["title"], 'UTF-8');
do
{
$price = $price + ($result_query["price"] * $result_query["buy_count_product"]);
```

Comment: Что-то не могу правильно всё сделать: 'mb_strtolower($result_query["title"],'UTF-8')' - не работает страница. Название у меня на английском.

Comment: @РоманШелест у вас в каком формате приходят данные из БД? в какой кодировке? и как вы их обрабатываете перед выводом? дополните вопрос кодом вывода данных из БД, чтобы можно было сказать более определенно.

Comment: Честно - без понятия в каком формате приходят данные из БД. Приложил всю страницу ибо что именно Вам необходимо показать, к сожалению, не понимаю.

Comment: @РоманШелест дополнил свой ответ

Comment: Вставляю $result_query["title"] = mb_strtolower($result_query["title"], 'UTF-8'); но не открывает страницу. Куда необходимо вставлять $result_query = mysql_fetch_array($query_product);?

Comment: @РоманШелест после `$result_query = mysql_fetch_array($query_product);` и перед `do`

Comment: @РоманШелест в той части, где вы уже выводите сам HTML

Comment: @РоманШелест + смотрите лог ошибок, что там пишется, очень помогает при отладке)

Comment: Я вообще ничего не понимаю, куда и что вставлять. Простите если сочтете за наглость, но не могли бы Вы вставить сами всё куда нужно?

Comment: @РоманШелест дополнил свой ответ, см. UPDATE 2

Comment: @РоманШелест на будущее переходите на Mysqli или PDO, mysql_query уже давно как depricated (если вообще не убраны из новых версий PHP).

Comment: Большое спасибо за терпение! Всё заработало так как нужно, скажите, а переходить на Mysqli или PDO сильно трудно? Нужно переписывать большую часть кода? Просто я в этом не понимаю... Да и движок написан не мною.

Comment: Теперь такой косяк, я сделал чтобы название ссылки было тоже "Test" но пишется теперь ведь с маленькой буквы, это конечно не так проблематично но всё же...

Comment: @РоманШелест вам надо просто разделить вывод, где требуется указывать с большой буквы - используете $result_query["title"], а где с маленькой, например $result_query["title_lower"]

Comment: @РоманШелест в принципе, перейти на Mysqli или PDO не сильно трудно, но нужно для начала почитать как и с чем их едят. по Mysqli там меняется код соединения с базой, а в большинстве функций просто используем mysqli, а не mysql. перейти на PDO немного более сложно (там в идеале надо писать свой класс-обертку), но тоже можно сделать в сжатый срок.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newNameTov = mb_strtolower($result_query["title"], 'UTF-8');

<TD  align="CENTER" ><a href="http://test.ru/'.$result_query["type_tovara"].'/'.$result_query["products_id"].'-'.$newNameTov.'">...</a> </TD>
```

Comment: Используя Ваш пример открывается вот так: http://test.ru/tshirts/3- То есть "test" не дописывает

Comment: **$result_query["title"]** не получаете. уверены что переменную `$newNameTov` выводите до вывода ссылки товара, и после того как получаете данные `$result_query` ?

Comment: @РоманШелест изменил. попробуйте так.

Comment: не показывает и дальше "test"...

Comment: @РоманШелест в какой кодировке сохранен файл? и какая кодировка при соединении с базой?

Comment: Кодировка файла UTF-8, а при соединении с базой - без понятия, как можно просмотреть?